# Why my \p{L} returns underscore?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code to parse by Regex:

```
        const string patern = @"^(\p{L}+)_";
        var rgx = new Regex(patern);
        var str1 = "library_log_12312_12.log";
        var m = rgx.Matches(str1);
```

It returns only one match and it is "library_". I have read a lot of resources and it should not contain underscore, should it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Maybe it's clearer for you if you use a look-behind instead of a group: `^\p{L}+(?=_)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern includes the `_`, so the match does too. If you only want the *group*, you need to specify that. It'll be in group 1 (as group 0 is always the whole match):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(\p{L}+)_");
        var input = "library_log_12312_12.log";
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        var match = matches[0];
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]); // library_
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // library
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I didn't understand in C# Regex. Apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex *ends* with `_` so basically, it matches on one or more Unicode letters, followed by an underscore (which is not a Unicode letter).

The captured group will not contain the `_`.

Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It should contain the underscore as it is in your regular expression.

If you only want to have `library` as the result, you need to access the first sub-group in the result:

```
var m = rgx.Matches(str1).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```